# Select JOINed substring

Tags: mysql, join

Is there some way to JOIN on a resulting substring?

I've got a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT _atc_codes.se, _atc_codes.code, SUBSTR(_atc_codes.code, 1, 1)
FROM diagnoses
JOIN _atc_codes
ON (_atc_codes.id = diagnoses.atc_code)
```

Now I want to add an extra column to this query which should be `SUBSTR(_atc_codes.code, 1, 1)` joined to its corresponding `_atc_codes.se`, how do I do that?

This image shows incorrect results, the 4th column should read "Matsmältningsorgan och ämnesomsättning" (corresponding cell in `_atc_codes.se`).

[image]

SQL Fidde: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6695d

Comment: do you want to add with the existing join or create another query column joins with a substring from a value of another column?

Comment: I want to add the column to the original SELECT query.

Comment: Could you please replace the images with plain text? The tiny font is hard to read, and impossible to copy and paste into sqlfiddle. Better yet, make your own sqlfiddle with sample data.

Comment: You can turn this into a pretty generic example. Are you on terms with what kind of result I want?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want. It would help if you showed sample input data and what you want the results to be.

Comment: What I'd like to do is copy your query into my answer and then edit it, but I can't.

Comment: See the first and second columns? They correspond to the same pair of values. See the third and fourth column? They correspond as well. The third column is a substring from the first column. Do I need two JOINs in my query thus?

Comment: I think you just need two JOINs.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how the second one should look like? Would really appreciate that.

Comment: I'm getting very confused. You seem to want to join `ON substr(code, 1, 1) = code` -- those are the same columns in the same table.

Comment: Pretty please would you post sample data and desired output. I'm sure that will unconfuse me.

Comment: Both column #2 and column #4 are taken from the same table, that's the problem.

Comment: But you've already joined the two tables, so just select the field you need... - Like Barnar already said: please provide some sample data for the two tables and an example of the desired output. You can use [SQL-fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) for the sample data.

Comment: Added an SQL Fiddle (just the Schema)

Comment: `CONCAT()` -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: Did one of my solutions help for you?

Comment: @rabudde I'm thinking of providing that column value via my Binding class instead, because that value will be the same for all rows anyway. Thanks for the suggestions though. I had difficulties formulating the question so that people would understand it ;)

Comment: Oh, using a framework was never part of your question, sorry. Nevertheless, I think my answer is the correct one for your question. So it would be great, if you verify my answer for this question and accept it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try (this example uses [MySQL user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html), it is important for this query that MySQL knows to use a value outside from subquery for comparision)

```
SELECT _atc_codes.se, _atc_codes.code,
@code_substr:=SUBSTR(_atc_codes.code, 1, 1) AS code_substr,
(
    SELECT se
    FROM _atc_codes
    WHERE code=@code_substr
    LIMIT 1
) AS code_substr_se
FROM diagnoses
JOIN _atc_codes ON _atc_codes.id = diagnoses.atc_code
```

Or (this example assigns table alias to outer table which is used in subquery because you are using a table twice and MySQL does not know which table to reference in `SUBSTR` in subquery):

```
SELECT outer_codes .se, outer_codes .code,
SUBSTR(outer_codes .code, 1, 1) AS code_substr,
(
    SELECT se
    FROM _atc_codes
    WHERE code=SUBSTR(outer_codes.code, 1, 1)
    LIMIT 1
) AS code_substr_se
FROM diagnoses
JOIN _atc_codes AS outer_codes ON outer_codes.id = diagnoses.atc_code
```

A third way would be adding a second `JOIN` and then group resultset like

```
SELECT _atc_codes_1st.se, _atc_codes_1st.code,
SUBSTR(_atc_codes_1st.code, 1, 1) AS code_substr,
MAX(_atc_codes_2nd.se) AS code_substr_se
FROM diagnoses
JOIN _atc_codes AS _atc_codes_1st ON _atc_codes_1st.id = diagnoses.atc_code
JOIN _atc_codes AS _atc_codes_2nd ON _atc_codes_2nd.code = SUBSTR(_atc_codes_1st.code, 1, 1)
GROUP BY _atc_codes_1st.se, _atc_codes_1st.code,code_substr
```

Deciding which variant to use, it would be the best to add a [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) to your query to show execution plan. Good luck.